# Full calendar showing events in wrong date for some months

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, symfony-1.4

[image]I am using full calendar version 1 with symfony 1.4. The months which doesn't have 30 days (Like March 31,May 31 etc.) event of 31st day overlap with event of 1st day of next month. I have tried googling and stack overflow existing questions. But couldn't solve it.

Comment: Can you provide your code how are you assigning the dates in the events.Cant figure out by just seeing the calendar

Comment: What is the full version # of fullcalendar that you are using? Also can you provide your json feed or array of events for the days that are not on the correct day?

Comment: I have found that in my database table date entry considers January as 1 index month. But in full calendar it is using 0 index. That is why it is showing duplicate entry. But database entry is correct. Also if consecutive two months have same number of days then it is not a problem. For example, Dec 2014 and Jan 2015 will show correctly as both of them has 31 days. I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: if you are getting your dates from the database then i suggest you convert your dates to calendar date and then used them in your full calendar. Plz provide your date array and code for how you are setting them in the events.